# Estructura de repetición y array en visual basic

Tags: array, bucles, vb

Me gustaría aprender cómo realizar un arreglo donde el usuario sea el que indique la cantidad de elementos del array

El profesor me solicita lo siguiente:

Declara las variables para luego asignar los valores de cada Textbox.
Crea una rutina de repetición **FOR**. Debes comenzar desde ValorInicial, hasta NumeroRepeticiones. **Salida**: En cada posición del arreglo debes colocarle el valor de posición d+ Cantidad a incrementar.
Muestra el contenido del arreglo en el ListBox

Ejemplo de salida del ListBox.: FOR (0) = 5

Hice la rutina de repetición, pero no entiendo cómo realizar la parte que dice:

Salida: En cada posición del arreglo debes colocarle el valor de posición d+ Cantidad a incrementar.
Muestra el contenido del arreglo en el ListBox

Ejemplo de salida del ListBox.: FOR (0) = 5

Quiere que se vea en el listbox la posición en el arreglo y la cantidad a incrementar y he buscado información, pero no he leído nada que me ayude.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Ok_button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Ok_button.Click

        Dim ValorInicial, CantidadIncrementar, NumeroRepeticiones As Integer
        Dim wrap As String

        ValorInicial = ValorInicial_textbox.Text
        NumeroRepeticiones = Repeticiones_textbox.Text
        CantidadIncrementar = CantidadIncrementar_textbox.Text

        wrap = Chr(13) & Chr(10)


        For i = ValorInicial To NumeroRepeticiones Step CantidadIncrementar

            ListBox1.Items.Add(i)
        Next


    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: Ejemplo]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Si en cada posicion del arreglo va el valor de la posicion (i) + (mas, suma, adicionar) la cantidad a incrementar, que deberias poner en lugar de ListBox1.Items.Add(i)??? esto es solo compresion de texto me parece.. porque vos misma escribiste que habia que hacer...

Comment: @gbianchi Saludos.  Estoy empezando en programación. Mi preocupación con el trabajo es que dice: Salida: En cada posición del arreglo debes colocarle el valor de posición d+ Cantidad a incrementar. Muestra el contenido del arreglo en el ListBox Ejemplo de salida del ListBox.: FOR (0) = 5 y francamente me da la percepción de que me falta algo. Y lo que pone de ejemplo. Yo sé que si lo entrego como está me va a reprobar

Comment: EL primer valor efectivamente tiene que ser 5.. porque?? por que i vale 1, y cantidad a incrementar vale 4, y 1+4 es 5.. el segundo valor es i que vale 5 y lo otro (4) por lo tanto es 9.. por lo menos eso entiendo yo...

Comment: @gbianchi gracias por tus respuestas.

Comment: por favor, lee los enlaces que te pase... lo mio son solo comentarios..

Answer (score 0):

No debería hacerte los deberes pero vaya...

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Ok_button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Ok_button.Click

        'Cuando declaras variables como tú lo tenías, únicamente la última es  Integer
        'el resto de variables son implicitamente variants.
        'Además de eso, no utilices integer, si supera los 32000 y algo te dará error
        'de overflow, utiliza long mejor.
        Dim ValorInicial As Long: ValorInicial = ValorInicial_textbox.Text
        Dim CantidadIncrementar As Long: CantidadIncrementar = CantidadIncrementar_textbox.Text
        Dim NumeroRepeticiones As Long: NumeroRepeticiones = Repeticiones_textbox.Text
        Dim wrap As String: wrap = Chr(13) & Chr(10) 'Esto no lo utilizas en el código

        'No habías declarado la i
        Dim i As Long
        'tu lógica para rellenar el listbox es que haces un bucle desde valor inicial a repeticiones
        'esto significa que si valor inicial es 20 y las repeticiones son 10, ya no te hace nada, por ejemplo.
        'utilizar el step con los incrementos, hace que te saltes repeticiones, así que no rellenaría todo.
        'debes hacer de 1 al máximo de repeticiones, y cada una es el valor inicial + la cantidad a incrementar * la repetición.
        For i = 1 To NumeroRepeticiones
            ListBox1.Items.Add ValorInicial + CantidadIncrementar * i
        Next

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Saludos Damian.  Gracias por tu ayuda.  Loque me gustó de tu respuesta fueron los comentarios explicando la solución, porque me permites aprender.

Comment: @Medusa resuelve tu problema esta respuesta?

Comment: pude comprobar efectivamente lo que me indicastes que si el valor inicial es 20 y la cantidad a incrementar es menor no hace nada.  Hice la modificación correspondiente.  Gracias.